# How do I stop a gas leak from my 150cc ice bear scooter?

Tags: moped

Gas leak on 150cc motor scooter I was riding then my engine stalled out then died and gas was leaking and burning on my muffler

Comment: How full was your gas tank when you started your trip?  Do you know if the gas was leaking before it stalled; IE: smell of gas fumes, or burning smell?  Was the gas tank empty when it stalled?

Comment: Leaking from where? tank? Pipe? valve?